# get value from var item?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have wp8 app that has list picker bind  to xml data sourse  and when I select item I want to be able to get "source" src location file location I have this function when I inspect the item i found src selected with name [image]

```
private void SoudListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.

    var item  = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show("Selected Item is : " + item);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` uses the resultant type on the right-hand side of the assignment statement to infer it's type, which (I believe) is `object` is this case.

To make the properties visible you need to cast the `SelectedItem` to it's actual type.

```
private void SoudListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.

    var item  = ((sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem) as Expression.Blend.SampleData.soundsEFXSampleDataSource3.sound;

    if(item != null)
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Item is : " + item.src);
}
```